# Identifying new entry between two tables

Tags: mysql

I would like to identify recent (since 60 days) entries in a table `T1` that are not in another table `T2`.

Since 'FULL OUTER JOIN' is not supported by MySQL, I have tried the code below.

I expect to find as a result a record from `T1` that I have erased from `T2`. The current code does not yield the expected result.

What's going wrong?

```
SELECT * FROM (

  SELECT store, name, date
  FROM `T1` A
  LEFT JOIN `T2` V
    ON A.name=V.namebis AND A.store=V.storebis

  UNION ALL 

  SELECT store, name, date
  FROM `T1` A
  RIGHT JOIN `T2` V
    ON A.name=V.namebis AND A.store=V.storebis
  WHERE A.name is null

) C
WHERE store IN (NYC, CHICAGO)
  AND (date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND subdate(CURRENT_DATE, 60))
GROUP BY store, name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to check which entries in `T1` are no longer in `T2`, you don't need a `FULL JOIN`, you can simply use a `LEFT JOIN` and check if the row no longer exists in `T2` by checking whether the fields in T2 are `NULL`. Note that the order of values in your `BETWEEN` clause is wrong, the lowest value must be first. I have fixed that below too.

```
SELECT store, name, date
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.name = T2.namebis AND T1.store = T2.storebis
WHERE store IN (NYC, CHICAGO)
  AND (date BETWEEN subdate(CURRENT_DATE, 60) AND CURRENT_DATE)
  AND T2.namebis IS NULL
```

Comment: If I put a specific date : `date='2019-04-08'` your answer seems to work. But not with `date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND subdate(CURRENT_DATE, 60)`

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Can you show some sample data?

Comment: If I put a specific date : `date='2019-04-08'` your answer works since I get lines in return. Oddly I don't not get those lines when I use the syntax: `date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND subdate(CURRENT_DATE, 60)`

Comment: @SamanthaAlexandria the order of your parameters to BETWEEN is incorrect, the lowest value must always come first. See my edit.

Comment: @SamanthaAlexandria no worries. I should have seen that earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT store, name, date
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 
ON (T1.name = T2.namebis AND T1.store = T2.storebis)
WHERE store IN (NYC, CHICAGO)
  AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, DATE(T1.`date`),CURDATE()) =60
  AND T2.namebis IS NULL
```